# Access to 3D array in fragment shader

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to provide access to a 3-dimensional array of scalar data to a fragment shader, from a Python program using PyOpenGL.

In the fragment shader, I declare the a 3d sampler uniform

```
uniform sampler3D vol;
```

and in the Python program I have the following code to set up a scalar 3d texture

```
vol = numpy.random.rand(3, 3, 3).astype(np.float32)
texture = glGenTextures(1)
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "vol"), 0)
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texture)
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED, 3, 3, 3, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, vol)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D)
```

However, no matter where from the sampler I take values, e.g.

```
color = texture(vol, vec3(0, 0, 0));
```

it appears that I always obtain black (0, 0, 0).

What am I doing wrong?

I know that the basic setup of my fragment shader works, i.e. if I write `color = vec3(1, 0, 0)` I get red pixels.

I also know that there are no OpenGL errors, because I'm running the program with the option `-glerror` processed by `glutInit()`, which leads to OpenGL errors being translated into Python exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem: Apparently GL_TEXTURE_3D is by default mipmapped, I only provided level 0, and (how I'm not clear about) another level is selected. The problem is solved by `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0)`.

Comment: That is weird as I am passing also non texture data this way and had no problems without `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0)`. May be its driver specific I am using **nVidia** gfx cards  or may be even environment specific as you are using different language and also using libs (not just GL/GLSL) so they might change some settings on their own too. Btw the `-glerror` option is handling just GL errors or also the GLSL errors? I am just curious I do not use GLUT

Comment: @Spektre, I have a GeForce GTX 1060 with official drivers. – Yes, it also reports GLSL compilation errors. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

That is because your `GL_RED` texture format is **clamped** to range `<0,1>` !!!

To remedy you need to use non clamped texture format or disable clamping ... Here examples that are working on my GL implementations:

- [GPU ray casting (single pass) with 3d textures in spherical coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568396/2521214)
- [GLSL back raytrace through 3D volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214)

here formats extracted from both:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R16F, xs,ys,zs, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, dat);

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RGBA8, size, size, size, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pdata);
```

For scalar data I would use the first option. There are more formats that are not clamped just try and see...

I have **never used** the disabling of clamping feature but saw this code somewhere while researching similar issues (not sure if it works):

```
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
```

With that theoretically you could use any texture format...

To verify you can use this:

- [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214)

Also I do not see any parameters of the texture set. I would expect something like this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,txrvol);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE);
```

to avoid interpolation messing your data for non exact texture coordinates ...

Comment: The possibility of disabling clamping is certainly interesting, but I don't see how that can be the problem: The data I pass are random values in the interval [0, 1], and the color components are specified in the same range...

Comment: @A.Donda have you verified that the generated texture is not just zeros? Also did you check GLSL compilation and link logs for errors? Did you tried the `GL_NEAREST` filtering on all 3 axises? All of these can cause wrong output ...

Comment: I figured it out, see my own answer. The solution suggests to me that a texture is not the best way to get non-image data into a fragment shader. Can you suggest a better way? I've seen that from 4.3, multidimensional array uniforms are supported...